# View a vmdk file from Python?

Tags: python, virtualization, abstraction, virtualbox, mount

Is there any way to view the contents of a vmdk file from Python, and to be able to read files from it? (I have no need to write to it). If not, is there any way to mount a vmdk file on a host machine, or generally any other way to look at a vmdk file without attaching it to a VM and running it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can mount a VMDK as a local disk with [Disk Mount Utility](http://www.petri.co.il/virtual_mount_vmware_virtual_disk_without_vmware.htm).

Comment: Neat. I'll just run the command from Python and view the disk that way.

Comment: This page is no longer available

Comment: @NirIzr - this answer is old enough to be an awkward teenager so perhaps it doesn't want to be seen.

Anyway, the wayback machine is your friend here: https://web.archive.org/web/20140907064107/https://petri.com/virtual_mount_vmware_virtual_disk_without_vmware.htm

Answer (score 1):

You may want to take a look at ctypes-vddk if you are looking to import modules for exfiltration of vmdk data through python. You can find the module here;  http://code.google.com/p/ctypes-vddk/

Personally, if you are looking to leverage the VDDK API (via C++), you can use Virtual Disk Development Kit 5.5 and its corresponding API.  The actually programming guide can also be found here:  hxxp://pubs.vmware.com/vsphere-55/topic/com.vmware.ICbase/PDF/vddk55_programming.pdf.  Additionally, there is a tool that implemented this which can be found here:  http://sourceforge.net/projects/vfae/.  Lastly, there was a writeup on the use of VDDK with regard to VMDK forensic analysis:  hxxp://crucialsecurityblog.harris.com/2012/01/18/how-can-vmwares-virtual-disk-development-kit-help-the-forensic-examiner/

enjoy...